# Creating django form for related models

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

I have the following models defined:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_of_answers = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want the user to be able to create a question along with its corresponding answers.

Basically, I want to create a form that will ask the user to enter a question and the number of answers for the question. Based on the number-of-answers specified, I want to then create that many text fields for each answer. I want to be able to connect each answer to its corresponding question in the database.

What is the best way to do this in Python Django? I have provided images of what this would look like visually. 
[Getting question and number of answers,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u7SZ.png)
[getting answers based on question and number of answers specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRLAL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would tackle this problem by using modelForms for creating questions, and then redirecting to a page where you can add the number of questions you specified when you created the question. This `add_answers` page won't use Django forms, we can just use a simple html form and then get the form data in the view. Here are the views:

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import QuestionForm
from .models import Question, Answer

# Create your views here.

def add_question(request):
    form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.cleaned_data.get('question')
            number_of_answers = form.cleaned_data.get('number_of_answers')
            create_question = Question.objects.create(question=question, number_of_answers=number_of_answers)
            create_question.save()
            return redirect('home:add-answers', id=create_question.id)
    return render(request, 'home/add_question.html', {'form': form})


def add_answers(request, id):
    question = Question.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        for i in request.POST.getlist('answers'):
            _ = Answer.objects.create(answer=i, question=id)
            _.save()

    num_answers = question.number_of_answers
    context = {"num_answers":range(num_answers), 'question':question}
    return render(request, 'home/add_answers.html', context)
```

`add_question` uses model forms:

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Question, Answer

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['question','number_of_answers']
```

We can access this form in the template:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
    {{ form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

For `add_answers`, we do the following:

```
<form method="POST" action=".">
    {% for i in num_answers %}
        <input type="text" name="answers"></input>
        <br />
    {% endfor %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

Where `num_answers` is a context variable that is `range(number_of_answers)`.

Edit: here is the **urls.py** file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add-answers/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.add_answers, name="add-answers"),
    url(r'^add-question/$', views.add_question, name="add-question"),
]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I have tried out your suggestion and I am getting a NoReverseMatch exception that says " 
Reverse for 'add_answers' not found. 'add_answers' is not a valid view function or pattern name." Do you know maybe why I am getting this error?

Comment: @km786 I updated my answer with **urls.py**. The error could be coming from `return redirect('home:add-answers', id=create_question.id)` if you didn't have the `add-answers` name set in urls.py. I hope that helps, let me know if you need more clarification. thanks

Comment: @km786 awesome! I'm glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look of [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/).And combine with [django-dynamic-forms](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/docs/usage.rst#provided-css-classes) can help you custom a web page to add question with answer.

Here is a demo of add a team with it's player.

models.py

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from .models import *


class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'


PlayerFormset = formset_factory(PlayerForm)


class TeamForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    players = PlayerFormset()
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import *
from .models import *


def post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeamForm(request.POST)

        player_instances = PlayerFormset(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if player_instances.is_valid():
                team = Team(name=form.cleaned_data['name'])
                team.save()
                args = {'form': form}
                for item in player_instances:
                    if item.is_valid():
                        player = item.save()
                        team.players.add(player)
                    else:
                        print('-----------error occur')
                team.save()
                return render(request, 'app1.html', args)

        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'app1.html', args)
    else:
        form = TeamForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'app1.html', args)
```

app1.html

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>gffdfdf</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/jquery.formset.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post" class="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Team</h2>
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }} : {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        {{ form.players.management_form }}

        <h3> Product Instance(s)</h3>
        <table id="table-product" class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>player name</th>
                <th>highest score</th>
                <th>age</th>
            </tr>

            </thead>
            {% for player in form.players %}
                <tbody class="player-instances">

                <tr>
                    <td>{{ player.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ player.score }}</td>
                    <td>{{ player.age }}</td>
                </tr>

                </tbody>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">save</button>

    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#myForm tbody tr').formset();
    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

screen like:
[image]